# JavaScript, open pdf encoded to Base64 in a new tab without downloading it in Google-Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, base64

After reading [this](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/GbVcuwg_QjM%5B1-25%5D) I understand that the desirable

```
window.open('data:application/pdf;base64,' + pdfDataBase64);
```

is not working because Google removed top-frame navigations to data URLs.

I found a nice workaround [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/682/what-does-the-not-allowed-to-navigate-top-frame-to-data-url-javascript-exception-means-in-google-chrome) so I replaced my code with

```
var win = window.open();
win.document.write('<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,' + pdfDataBase64 + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
```

which works but gives me this in the console:

> [Deprecation] HTML Imports is deprecated and will be removed in M73,
>   around March 2019. Please use ES modules instead. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5144752345317376 for more
>   details.
>
> [Deprecation]
>   document.registerElement is deprecated and will be removed in M73,
>   around March 2019. Please use window.customElements.define instead.
>   See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4642138092470272 for more
>   details.
>   (anonymous)   @   polymer-micro-extracted.js:442
>
> [Deprecation] Element.createShadowRoot
>   is deprecated and will be removed in M73, around March 2019. Please
>   use Element.attachShadow instead. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4507242028072960 for more
>   details.
>   _createLocalRoot   @   polymer-mini-extracted.js:2083

I am not so familiar with javascript and I'm afraid that the code I'm using now won't work as of March 2019.

Is there any reason for concern or should I ignore this messages?

Is there any other way I can open the Base64 pdf in a new tab, without downloading it?

Comment: It's coming from `polymer-micro-extracted.js`, do you have some chrome extension plugin,.. Your code shouldn't be the cause here.

Comment: @Keith, I saw that but I didn't know how to interpret it, I don't have any chrome extensions other than Google Docs. I am not sure when or why polymer-mini-extracted.js is running

Comment: It's maybe what your using to view pdf's,.  But opening a pdf inside an iframe shouldn't be giving you any errors, if it does, it's the pdf viewer that's doing it.   Normally in chrome if you click on the Javascript file, it will open & it might then give some hints were it's coming from.

Comment: Also, to have full control of viewing PDF's, instead of relying on whatever PDF viewer the user has registered, you could have a look at https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/  You then wouldn't even need an iFrame.

Comment: @Keith  so the warnings are coming from the chrome's pdf viewer, I see now. I should't worry about them then, thank you